# Iptables firewall rules not restoring on server restart

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I am setting up iptables on a new instance of Ubuntu 14.04 server.
So far I have:

- put iptables rules into a file `/etc/iptables.firewall.rules`
- created a script `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload.sh` and put the following code in it

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
exit 0
```

The firewall rules work, e.g. if I manualy  run the command from a prompt

```
$ iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
```

the iptables rules get applied. But when I reboot the server the firewall is not up - how can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest you use the full path to binaries, `/sbin/iptables-restore`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is the hackish method.

You should consider installing the `iptables-persistent` package which automatically will handle loading up of `iptables` rules at boot.

This will store rules in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `/etc/iptables/rules.v6` and will load at boot.  Make revisions to those files and restore from those if you edit your rule sets.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying your suggestion now. will post back with the outcome

Comment: @user4668401 You're welcome.  I always advise against trying to home-grow a solution when an easy one exists in the repositories ;)

Comment: This is the probably the easiest solution. FWIW, for the vast majority of users ufw may be a better solution. If you are familiar with iptables it is trivial to learn and the rule set is maintained by a team of security experts rather then everyone writing his or her own rules. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: @bodhi.zazen agreed with you, but given OP said they were setting up `iptables`... I chose to ignore ufw in this case :P

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I originally looked at UFW but I couldnt understand how it worked - however Iptables made sense to me immediately - also I use Iptables with fail2ban and intend to use iptables for performing mass IP address blocking on a webserver - Im not sure if UFW would work for any of those tasks?

Comment: iptables will perform fail2ban functionality. maintaining a long blacklist is an exercise in futility, IMO, as black hats will spoof or change ip and such blacklists tend to affect legitimate users. http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/iptables#Additional_Tips , scroll down to   "Use iptables to reject/block failed connections"

Comment: limiting connections makes the black hats go away faster and automatically. The automated ssh scans move on fairly fast for example and rate limits on http help as well, but the parameters for http are much more liberal then ssh.